# Java swing swapping ImagePanels in a ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

I have a set of images that I want to present in a JFrame.  They are all the same size - each image fills the JFrame. I swap between which is visible, layer style:

```
    f = new JFrame("xx");
    f.setSize(480, 854);
    contentPane = f.getContentPane();
    ip1 = new ImagePanel(new File("assets/1.jpg"));
    ip2 = new ImagePanel(new File("assets/2.jpg"));
    ip3 = new ImagePanel(new File("assets/3.jpg"));
    f.setVisible(true);
    contentPane.add(ip1);
    contentPane.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

An ImagePanel is:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public ImagePanel(File imageFile) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Image could not be read: " + imageFile);
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And I try swapping between them in the MouseListener:

```
static MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {

    private int i = 1;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // logger.log(Level.INFO, e.toString());
        contentPane.removeAll();
        if (++i > 3) i = 1;
        switch (i) {
            case 1: contentPane.add(ip1); break;
            case 2: contentPane.add(ip2); break;
            case 3: contentPane.add(ip3); break;            
        }
        contentPane.repaint();
    }
};
```

The first image displays as desired. Click gives me white, and same on 2nd click, and third brings me back round to my first image as desired.  If I click on the *frame* in between clicks on the white, the 2nd and 3rd images appear, and once rendered it works as expected.   What am I missing?

Ack, newbs!  No doubt there is a much better way...

thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (My answer was based entirely on the word 'swap'.)

Comment: BTW - do you intend to add things (e.g. components) to the `ImagePanel`?  If not, a `JLabel` as suggested by mKorbel is much easier.

Comment: I plan on analyzing ARGB in the BufferedImages (read only).  I did see JLabel but it was unclear how to get to each's BufferedImage.  Thanks for the SSCCE ref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both panels in a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

Answer (score 4):

put your `Images` as [Icon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html),

rulles for Swing GUI

- is [JComponent(s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) already visible
- you want to swap betweens this/these Object(s)

then you have to call

```
myLabel.setIcon(myIconn);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of `JLabel`,  OTOH 1) the `repaint()` is unnecessary after setting a different `Icon` 2) The code would only have to call `revalidate()` if the images were of different size,  whereas the OP states.. *"They are all the same size"*.

Comment: The OP has confirmed no other components are to go into the panel, so I think 'use a `JLabel`' is the best approach.

Comment: SetIcon works as expected, but I am unable to find a way to read the underlying Raster.  So I've not yet got the answer I want.. I'll look at CardLayout.